# Custom OrderBy on a List of List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to orderby on a List like:

```
public List<Person> personList { get; set; };    

class Person
{
    public string Name{ get; set; };
    public List<Car> carList{ get; set; };
}

class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public int PriceInMillions { get; set; };
}
```

I want to sort `CarList` of each `PersonList` such that `CarList` has `BMW object(can be one or more)` at top of list?

Input:

```
Person: Name: 'ABC'
List<Car>:{{"x",25},{"y",25},{"BMW",26},{"x",25},{"BMW",25}}

Person: Name: 'DEF'
List<Car>:{{"BMW",21},{"y",25},{"BMW",26},{"x",25},{"BMW",20}}
```

Required Output:

```
Person: Name: 'ABC'
List<Car>:{{"BMW",25},{"BMW",26},{"x",25},{"y",25},{"x",25}}

Person: Name: 'DEF'
List<Car>:{{"BMW",20},{"BMW",21},{"BMW",26},{"y",25},{"x",25}}
```

I tried to find the index of "BMW" and swap it with first index but it is not working.

Comment: I have no idea regarding this scenario, I tried but it is not working and not in presentable form.

Comment: Do you want to sort the cars alphabetically, or keep the order the same and only move BMW to the top?

Comment: no just BMW at top is my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working solution:

```
public List<Person> GetSortedList(List<Person> personList)
{
   foreach (var person in personList)
   {
       person.CarList=person.CarList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name== "BMW").ToList();
   }
 return personList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Car> orderedCarList = person.carList.OrderBy(s => (s.Name == "BMW") ? 0 : 1).ToList();
person.carList = orderedCarList;
```

Comment: it is personList not person and need List<person> sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort in-place, without creating a new list or cars for each person, you can do

```
foreach(Person p in personList)
{
    p.carList.Sort((car1, car2) =>
        -(car1.Name == "BMW").CompareTo(car2.name == "BMW"));
}
```